# In JavaScript, when using Regex, how to match a space without using a space character OR \s?

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript, block, space

When using [block regular expressions](http://coffeescript.org/#regexes) in CoffeeScript, spaces are stripped out. So, I can't match a space unless I use `\s`, but that also matches new lines, tabs, etc.

So in JavaScript (since other than block regular expressions, CoffeeScript regular expressions are the same as JavaScript's), is there a way to match ONLY spaces without using a space itself?

Comment: Why don't you use ` `?

Comment: Does `\ ` work? That's a backslash followed by a space.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Yes it does.  Its a little more difficult to read than your current answer, though (in my opinion).

Comment: put the space in a character class: `[ ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could encode the space in the hexadecimal representation `\x20`.

**Example:**

```
"hello world".match(/o\x20w/)
```

**Returns:**

```
["o w"]
```

**Alternatively:**

While not exactly what was asked, you can get around the issue of CoffeeScript stripping the space if you escape it with a backslash like this `\` .

Comment: Why you escaped `o` and `w`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm asking myself that same question right now. There's no reason to, I removed it.